# Parsing devicetree with pyparsing into structured dictionary

Tags: python, pyparsing, device-tree

For my [C++ RTOS](http://distortos.org/) I'm writing a parser of devicetree "source" files (`.dts`) in Python using pyparsing module. I'm able to parse the structure of the devicetree into a (nested) dictionary, where the property name or node name are dictionary keys (strings), and property values or nodes are dictionary values (either string or a nested dictionary).

Let's assume I have the following example devicetree structure:

```
/ {
    property1 = "string1";
    property2 = "string2";
    node1 {
        property11 = "string11";
        property12 = "string12";
        node11 {
            property111 = "string111";
            property112 = "string112";
        };
    };
    node2 {
        property21 = "string21";
        property22 = "string22";
    };
};
```

I'm able to parse that into something like that:

```
{'/': {'node1': {'node11': {'property111': ['string111'], 'property112': ['string112']},
                 'property11': ['string11'],
                 'property12': ['string12']},
       'node2': {'property21': ['string21'], 'property22': ['string22']},
       'property1': ['string1'],
       'property2': ['string2']}}
```

However for my needs I would prefer to have this data structured differently. I would like to have all properties as a nested dictionary for key "properties", and all child nodes as a nested dictionary for key "children". The reason is that the devicetree (especially nodes) have some "metadata" which I would like to have just as key-value pairs, which requires me to move actual "contents" of the node one level "lower" to avoid any name conflicts for the key. So I would prefer the example above to look like this:

```
{'/': {
  'properties': {
    'property1': ['string1'],
    'property2': ['string2']
  },
  'nodes': {
    'node1': {
      'properties': {
        'property11': ['string11'],
        'property12': ['string12']
      }
      'nodes': {
        'node11': {
          'properties': {
            'property111': ['string111'],
            'property112': ['string112']
          }
          'nodes': {
          }
        }
      }
    },
    'node2': {
      'properties': {
        'property21': ['string21'],
        'property22': ['string22']
      }
      'nodes': {
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I've tried to add "name" to the parsing tokens, but this results in "doubled" dictionary elements (which is expected, as this behaviour is described in pyparsing documentation). This might not be a problem, but technically a node or property can be named "properties" or "children" (or whatever I choose), so I don't think such solution is robust.

I've also tried to use `setParseAction()` to convert the token into a dictionary fragment (I hoped that I could transform `{'key': 'value'}` into `{'properties': {'key': 'value'}}`), but this did not work at all...

Is this at all possible directly with pyparsing? I'm prepared to just do a second phase to transform the original dictionary to whatever structure I need, but as a perfectionist I would prefer to use a single-run pyparsing-only solution - if possible.

For a reference here's a sample code (Python 3) which transforms the devicetree source into an "unstructured" dictionary. Please note that this code is just a simplification which doesn't support all the features found in `.dts` (any data type other than string, value lists, unit-addresses, labels and so on) - it just supports string properties and node nesting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyparsing
import pprint

nodeName = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas, pyparsing.alphanums + ',._+-', max = 31)
propertyName = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + ',._+?#', max = 31)
propertyValue = pyparsing.dblQuotedString.setParseAction(pyparsing.removeQuotes)
property = pyparsing.Dict(pyparsing.Group(propertyName + pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Literal('=').suppress() +
        propertyValue) + pyparsing.Literal(';').suppress()))
childNode = pyparsing.Forward()
rootNode = pyparsing.Dict(pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.Literal('/') + pyparsing.Literal('{').suppress() +
        pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(property) + pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(childNode) +
        pyparsing.Literal('};').suppress()))
childNode <<= pyparsing.Dict(pyparsing.Group(nodeName + pyparsing.Literal('{').suppress() +
        pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(property) + pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(childNode) +
        pyparsing.Literal('};').suppress()))

dictionary = rootNode.parseString("""
/ {
    property1 = "string1";
    property2 = "string2";
    node1 {
        property11 = "string11";
        property12 = "string12";
        node11 {
            property111 = "string111";
            property112 = "string112";
        };
    };
    node2 {
        property21 = "string21";
        property22 = "string22";
    };
};
""").asDict()
pprint.pprint(dictionary, width = 120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really so close. I just did the following:

- added `Group`s and results names for your "properties" and "nodes" sub-sections
- changed some of the punctuation literals to CONSTANTS (`Literal("};")` will fail to match if there is space between the closing brace and semicolon, but `RBRACE + SEMI` will accommodate whitespace)
- removed the outermost `Dict` on `rootNode`

Code:

```
LBRACE,RBRACE,SLASH,SEMI,EQ = map(pyparsing.Suppress, "{}/;=")
nodeName = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphas, pyparsing.alphanums + ',._+-', max = 31)
propertyName = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + ',._+?#', max = 31)
propertyValue = pyparsing.dblQuotedString.setParseAction(pyparsing.removeQuotes)
property = pyparsing.Dict(pyparsing.Group(propertyName + EQ 
                                          + pyparsing.Group(propertyValue)
                                          + SEMI))
childNode = pyparsing.Forward()
rootNode = pyparsing.Group(SLASH + LBRACE
                           + pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(property))("properties")
                           + pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(childNode))("children")
                           + RBRACE + SEMI)
childNode <<= pyparsing.Dict(pyparsing.Group(nodeName + LBRACE
                                             + pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(property))("properties")
                                             + pyparsing.Group(pyparsing.ZeroOrMore(childNode))("children")
                                             + RBRACE + SEMI))
```

Converting to a dict with asDict and printing with pprint gives:

```
pprint.pprint(result[0].asDict())
{'children': {'node1': {'children': {'node11': {'children': [],
                                                'properties': {'property111': ['string111'],
                                                               'property112': ['string112']}}},
                        'properties': {'property11': ['string11'],
                                       'property12': ['string12']}},
              'node2': {'children': [],
                        'properties': {'property21': ['string21'],
                                       'property22': ['string22']}}},
 'properties': {'property1': ['string1'], 'property2': ['string2']}}
```

You can also use the `dump()` method that is included with pyparsing's `ParseResults` class, to help visualized the list and dict/namespace-style access to the results as-is, without any conversion call necessary

```
print(result[0].dump())

[[['property1', ['string1']], ['property2', ['string2']]], [['node1', [['property11', ['string11']], ['property12', ['string12']]], [['node11', [['property111', ['string111']], ['property112', ['string112']]], []]]], ['node2', [['property21', ['string21']], ['property22', ['string22']]], []]]]
- children: [['node1', [['property11', ['string11']], ['property12', ['string12']]], [['node11', [['property111', ['string111']], ['property112', ['string112']]], []]]], ['node2', [['property21', ['string21']], ['property22', ['string22']]], []]]
  - node1: [[['property11', ['string11']], ['property12', ['string12']]], [['node11', [['property111', ['string111']], ['property112', ['string112']]], []]]]
    - children: [['node11', [['property111', ['string111']], ['property112', ['string112']]], []]]
      - node11: [[['property111', ['string111']], ['property112', ['string112']]], []]
        - children: []
        - properties: [['property111', ['string111']], ['property112', ['string112']]]
          - property111: ['string111']
          - property112: ['string112']
    - properties: [['property11', ['string11']], ['property12', ['string12']]]
      - property11: ['string11']
      - property12: ['string12']
  - node2: [[['property21', ['string21']], ['property22', ['string22']]], []]
    - children: []
    - properties: [['property21', ['string21']], ['property22', ['string22']]]
      - property21: ['string21']
      - property22: ['string22']
- properties: [['property1', ['string1']], ['property2', ['string2']]]
  - property1: ['string1']
  - property2: ['string2']
```

Comment: Many thanks! Just one more question - is it possible to have empty keys as an empty dict `{}` instead of empty list `[]` (this is seen here - `'node11': {'children': []...`)? Or maybe just not have such keys at all if they are empty?